# TFS 2015 SQL Server evaluation period has expired

Tags: tfs

I am taking over the TFS 2015 a previous employee set up.

When trying to access the webapp I am getting an HTTP 500 error "The website is under maintenance".

When trying to open the Team Foundation Server Administration Console I am getting the "... TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database..."

When looking at the SQL Server ERRORLOG I am seeing the "SQL Server evaluation period has expired."

It seems to me previous employee setup the trial version of TFS 2015.

How could I verify this is true and how can I upgrade the version to a purchased license?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is "`SQL Server evaluation period has expired`."

You can try testing the SQL Server instance in TFS Administration Console (Generally the test connection should be failed if the SQL license expired) :

```
Select specific Collection --> Stop the collecion --> Edit Settings --> Test
```

To activate the SQL Server again, you need an edition upgrade for SQL Server . To upgrade, you need to have installation media of the destination version. SQL Server evaluation edition can be upgraded to **standard**, **developer**, **enterprise** editions.

Here are the steps:

1. From SQL Server installation media, launch setup.exe.
2. From the SQL Server Installation Center click **Maintenance**, and then
   select **Edition Upgrade**
3. It would launch Wizard where you need to keep on pressing next, next
   and finally “Upgrade”. Make sure that edition shown in the license
   terms screen is what you purchased.

Please refer to [SQL SERVER – Evaluation Period Has Expired – How to Activate SQL Server?](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/06/22/sql-server-evaluation-period-has-expired-how-to-activate-sql-server/) for details.

[image]